# Running a cleanup of icloud desktop on load

Tags: launchd

I have the following launchd saved as an agent in: `/Users/my_name/Library/LaunchAgents`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.desktop.cleanup</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>zsh</string>
            <string>-c</string>
            <string>/usr/local/bin/trash ~/Desktop/Screen*</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>3600</integer>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/local.desktop.cleanup.err</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/local.desktop.cleanup.out</string>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NetworkState</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

It runs a very simple [program](https://github.com/ali-rantakari/trash) that moves, instead of *removes*, the selected files to the bin. I've only been testing the launchd's success with RunAtLoad and I cannot get it to work. I get the following error in my log file after each time I log in:

```
zsh:1: no matches found: /Users/my_name/Desktop/Screen*
```

My Desktop is actually one of those icloud folders that I suppose MacOS just has symlinked. My theory is that maybe these files do not exist locally at the point the program is run. If this is the case, or not, I would appreciate any ideas or solutions to make this specific use case work.

N.B. You'll noticed I left KeepAlive NetworkState in to show I attempted to delay the run until the network was "alive", however, this wouldn't account for downloading any files.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I managed to work out the problem. Unfortunately, it was the usual culprit: The heavy privacy permissions system MacOS has been relying on since Catalina!

Since I was running the command from `zsh` in order to effectively get the correct user context for relative directories I had to the following:

[image]

Now, I am concerned that these somewhat defeats the purpose of this hardened security. I would really appreciate any information as to how it might be best to allow this to run without opening up my whole OS to zsh... Perhaps `launchd` or `launchctl`? I fear those are still quite open.

Comment: Possibly write a shell script to do the trashing and put that in the plist. If the shell script starts with the #!/bin/zsh line then it should run and hopefully you only need to give that script the permission.